# Help with router and spotty wireless

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

Time Warner Cable/ Road Runner router shows up some times on the network list on Mac OS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard. It makes a spotty appearence on the list.

The router is a SMC Networks Model # SMC8014WG-SI. The default gateway numbers all do not work.

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.2.1
- 10.10.10.1

What IP adress am I looking for here to log in to the router to fix the issue? Is the router blocking my request?

EDIT:

- 192.168.0.0 also fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this?

```
Internet---|-CM----Mac
           |
           |-CM----Phone
```

Are the CM's set up to DHCP?  Are the Mac and Phone set for DHCP?  Where is the router?

Comment: The `CM` connected to the Mac is the router. --- There is a PC hard wired into the same CM as the Mac. The Mac is connecting wirelessly, which is part of the issue - spotty wireless.

Comment: does the other CM have wireless capability?  Is it on?  How far away is the Mac from the CM?  How many obstructions between the CM and the Mac?

Comment: Only the CM for the internet has wireless. The phone company came down to the client's house. Apparently they need the computer on to run the phone. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
netstat -r
```

should give you the list of routes, including the default gateway in use.

If that doesn't help, check your own ip address and perform a ping scan of the subnet you're on using nmap.

Comment: This shows the default gateway as 192.168.0.1

Comment: how do i do a ping scan?

Comment: nmap -v -sP 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the router?

Comment: @bryan - It's a wireless router/modem in one unit plugged into a (cable cable as in television type) cable. There is a separate modem plugged into a cable for the Voip phone. Each of the two devices are getting cable from a splitter on the original line. They are independent of each other. The internet now works on the LAN, but the wireless is now locked and wasn't before and was before that. Also, the VOIP phone is dead. Ugh, TimeWarner/RoadRunner!!

Comment: Is there a "reset" button on the wireless, to set it back an unconfigured state? 

Try this also - turn off wireless on your computer and connect it to the router using an ethernet cable. Check if you can access it configuration that way.

Comment: it's a no go. I've read elsewhere that RR/TW locks ppl out of the equipment in this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have two cable modems?  The usual deployment of CATV internet is

```
Internet----CM----SOHO RTR----Your devices
```

If you do have two cable modems were they both provided by the ISP?

Comment: Interestingly enough, yes. The router seems to be a modem as it is in parallel to the modem  for the Voip, not in sequence. PS- not me, a client. Yes, both form the ISP.